# RedirectTo page with key

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I redirect to page with key ?i.e. I want to redirect to specifc entry on the table ,how should I do that ?
 I need something like **RedirectToAction("Edit" ,"2" )**;,how should I do that ?

for example here I redirect to page index but

RedirectToAction("Index");

Comment: can you please be more specific with the requirements.
(Please provide your function definition atleast)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Edit method is `public ActionResult Edit(int ID) {...`, then

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { ID = 2 });
```